# Can you write a unit test for a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Kind of a meta question, but I was wondering if there would ever be cases where writing a unit test for a unit test would make sense.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining how a test for a unit test would differ from the unit test itself.

Comment: If you could, how could you test that it actually tested the unit test?

Comment: As the user has said, it's a bit meta. I believe they are asking if the unit test itself is a good test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write a test for that, generally its considered Mutation Testing.

> Mutation Testing is a type of software testing in which certain statements of the source code are changed/mutated to check if the test cases are able to find errors in source code. The goal of Mutation Testing is ensuring the quality of test cases in terms of robustness that it should fail the mutated source code.

From [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/mutation-testing.html)

There's a few well known examples,

- [PIT](http://pitest.org/) for Java
- [MytPy](https://pypi.org/project/MutPy/) for Python
- [Stryker](https://stryker-mutator.io/) looks like its the one for Javascript.

You could write you own tests that mutate your code itself, but its sensible to use OSS projects and help contribute to them if theres any unique needs given the complexity of the area. You don't want to have to own your own mutating framework either and all the maintance with that.